# How to display a post attachment in Wordpress depending on the caption value

Tags: wordpress, attachment, caption, qtranslate

I would like to display automatically a post attachment (PDF) depending on the language of my blog (french and english).

When the post is displaying in french version, I would like display the french PDF, and when the post is displaying in english, the english one.

I use the qtranslate pluggin and I though to use the caption of the attachment ("fr" or "en") to create a sort of conditional tag.

I tried the code below but it does'nt work. Do you have any idea to help me?

Many thanks in advance,
Dem.

```
<!-- PDF EN -->
<?php if(qtrans_getLanguage()=='en'): ?>
    <?php
        if ( $attachments = get_children( array(
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'post_mime_type' => array('application/doc','application/pdf','application/msword'),
            'numberposts' => 1,
            'post_status' => null,
            'post_parent' => $post->ID,
            ))) ;
            foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
            if ($attachment->post_excerpt == 'en') {
                echo '<a href="' . wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID ) . '"><img src="' .get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/images/pdf.png" alt="Pdf" class="pdf" /></a>';
                echo '';
            }
            }
    ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<!-- PDF FR -->
<?php if(qtrans_getLanguage()=='fr'): ?>
    <?php
        if ( $attachments = get_children( array(
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'post_mime_type' => array('application/doc','application/pdf','application/msword'),
            'numberposts' => 1,
            'post_status' => null,
            'post_parent' => $post->ID,
            ))) ;
            foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
            if ($attachment->post_excerpt == 'fr') {
                echo '<a href="' . wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID ) . '"><img src="' .get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/images/pdf.png" alt="Pdf" class="pdf" /></a>';
                echo '';
            }
            }
    ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: what part doesn't work? is it hitting either conditional?

Comment: Thanks for helping me, mikevoermans. The english is ok, but when I swith in the french version (=default language), the PDF doesn't display.

Comment: OMG! By writing this comment, I found the solution! "'numberposts' => 1," should be deleted. Thanks again to you!

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple fix that allows you to select the language for multimedia files using Wordpress qTranslate plugin

https://github.com/rafaelcalleja/qTranslateMultimediaLanguage

Comment: Updated for latest version too?